# Inaccurate UI button unity

Tags: unity, gui

[image]

As you see in this screenshot I must hover the mouse on that that spot to click on button in overall you must hover the mouse upper than button to click on it, tried to change the Sprite but even with default Sprite I have this problem so I don't think there is problem with Sprites.

Let me explain more about this panel:
In this scene I have two canvas's one for Pause button only and another one for this panel that is disabled. When you click on Pause this panel will appear ( second canvas will be activated. Why is that? I tried to change some things in the canvas like change UI scale mode to scale with screen size but no luck.
I will be grateful for help I don't really know where problem is.
[image]

Update : I just now found very odd behavior when hit play if mouse be in game view that problem wont occur, after mouse leave the button issue will appear again.

Comment: We'll need to see a bit more detail of how this is configured in your scene. Can you show us the scene view of this button, and how it and its children are arranged in the hierarchy?

Comment: need to see a img of the Canvas and button setup.  is it just the Resume button? if so id just duplicate the working button and set that to the resume and delete the problem button. I have ran into this issue before back when 4.6 was first released but haven't been able to re-create the problem.

Comment: ok i will update with more screenshots and no its not only resume button all buttons in panel have this issude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I've finally solved my problem and issue was texts on buttons looks like i scaled them and made them bigger than buttons.

Comment: If you solved your problem you should mark the question as "answered".

Comment: oh i forgot that :)